# Contingency table from a 2x3 dataframe in r

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, contingency

I have this df

```
Genero   Frustrado  No frustrado
<chr>      <int>        <int>
Hombre      138           9 
Mujer       145          12
```

And I need to turn it into a contingency table like this:

```
                Frustrado  
Genero       Si          No
    
Hombre      138           9 
Mujer       145          12
```

How can I do it with a simple code chunk?
(I need to replicate this many times and I would prefer not to write vectors every time)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
`dimnames<-`(
  as.table(as.matrix(df[-1])),
  list(Genero = df$Genero, Frustrado = c("si", "No"))
)
```

which gives

```
        Frustrado
Genero    si  No
  Hombre 138   9
  Mujer  145  12
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Genero = c("Hombre", "Mujer"), Frustrado = c(138L,
145L), `No frustrado` = c(9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Thomas but I don't quite understand the first part of the code `dimnames<-`. I ran it and it throws this error "Error in df$Genero : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: @AleRey that's because Thomas is very reasonably assuming your tibble is called `df`.Change `df` in this code to the name of your data frame and it should work

Comment: @AleRey `dimnames<-` assigns names to dimensions of table. I guess you got that error since you have factors in your `df`. Try  `df <- type.convert(df,as.is = TRUE)` first and then ran the code above.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, but I had done it an that was the output anyway. 

`dimnames<-`(
  as.table(as.matrix(tabla_genero_pivot[-1])),
  list(Genero = tabla_genero_pivot$Genero, Frustrado = c("si", "No"))
)

Comment: @Thomas that was all about! I did what you said and works perfectly! Cheers!

Comment: @AllanCameron, the error that throwed after I changed the df (the first time I had forgotten) was actually this one:  Error in dimnames(as.table(as.matrix(frustracion_genero_pivot[-1])), list(Genero = frustracion_genero_pivot$Genero,  : 
  2 arguments passed to 'dimnames' which requires 1

Answer (score 1):

We can use `column_to_rownames`

```
library(tibble)
out <- df %>%
          column_to_rownames('Genero') %>%
          as.matrix

names(dimnames(out)) <- names(df)[1:2]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Genero = c("Hombre", "Mujer"), Frustrado = c(138L,
145L), `No frustrado` = c(9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```